# ¿Por qué esta función se me activa al 3er click?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Necesito que esta función de notificación se abra al hacer clic en ella, pero se me activa al tercer clic y no puedo entender. Acá, en las siguientes líneas está descrita la situación.

Al hacer clic acá:

```
<li class="bold">
  <a class="dropdown-trigger btn blue" onclick="notificacion2()" href="#!" data-target="notificacion">
    <i class="material-icons">notifications</i>
  </a>
</li>
```

Se deberia abrir acá, pero se abre al tercer clic:

```
<ul id="notificacion" class="dropdown-content"></ul>
```

Con está función:

```
function notificacion2(){
 $.ajax({ //se inicia la petición ajax al archivo que consulta los mensajes en la base de datos
          type : 'GET',
          dataType : 'json',
          url : uri+'admin/notificacion/' //url del archivo a consultar         
  }).done((respuesta)=>{
    if(respuesta.length>0){
      respuesta.forEach((e,i)=>{
        var text = e.noti;
        $("#notificacion").append(                               
                     `<li><a>`+text+`</a></li>`
        );
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Pero se abre al tercer clic.

Por favor ayuda. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Se abre al tercer click, o es que no estas esperando despues del primer click, que haga el pedido y vuelva?

Comment: Posiblemente no es que se esté "abriendo" al tercer clic, sino que el tiempo de respuesta de esa petición ajax tiene un delay y se renderiza tarde.

Comment: Utiliza fetch para las peticiones es bueno aprender a trabajar con API's mas modernas y por otro lado, el comentario de arriba puede estar en lo cierto, inhabilita el botón/link hasta que haya una respuesta y así descartas el problema, saludos.

Comment: @kleith, no es que se demore en abrir, puedes dar un clic en el boton que de seguro no se va abrir en una hora, hay que dar los 3 clics

Comment: @DєηyηCrawford Me podrias ayudar a hacer lo que me dijiste? mucha sgracias

Comment: la clase `dropdown-trigger` puede estar interfiriendo: al primer click tira la peticion y "abre" el dropdown vacío, al segundo click cierra el dropdown vacio, al tercer click abre el dropdown con el resultado del ajax del primer click. Qué framework css+javascript estas usando aparte de jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

prueba poner así tu etiqueta

```
 <a class="btn blue" onclick="notificacion2()" href="javascript:void(0)">
       <i class="material-icons">notifications</i>
 </a>
```

Pon tu href de esta forma, siempre lo uso así cuando quiero usar el onclick

Answer (score 0):

Deberias probar con el siguiente código:

```
 <li class="bold">
    <a class="dropdown-trigger btn blue" href="javascript:notificacion2()" data-target="notificacion">
    <i class="material-icons">notifications</i>
    </a>
</li>
```